# javascript array passed by reference but

Tags: javascript

Why console.log(a) doesn't return same result [1, 2, 3, 4] as console.log(b) ?

```
function test(c, d) {
  c = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  d.push(4);
}

a = [1, 2, 3];
b = [1, 2, 3];
test(a, b);
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

Comment: Because `a` in `test` function is a local variable to that function, and you're overriding the passed reference to the array `a` in the outer scope.

Comment: but same as b no ?

Comment: Not the same, you're accessing the reference `b`, not overriding it. Reference is also a value, passing a reference doesn't break the variable scope.

Comment: @Ivar I know that, my question is more specific about array ;)

Comment: @Teemu ok that should be the reason, now is there something in the spec or whatever that it was designed this way ?

Comment: To avoid shadow variable, I renamed variable in `test` function to `c and d`

Comment: @user310291 An array is also an object. If you assign a new value to a variable that you passed as a parameter, you overwrite the parameter's value, not the original.

Comment: @Ivar but b is same kind of array ;)

Comment: @user310291 [Somewhere in the depths](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-functions-and-classes.html#sec-parameter-lists), you've just to dig it out.

Comment: @user310291 Both `a` and `b` are two separate arrays that you pass. The assignment operator assigns a new value to the parameter, but doesn't do so to the variable that you passed (`a`). This is because JS is pass-by-value. If you use `.push()` then you are performing modifications to the referenced array, with is the same as the one you passed if you don't reassign a value to `d`. This is what the duplicate (tries to) explain(s).

Comment: @Teemu ok thanks I get it ;)

Comment: @Ivar ok thanks you're right I now get it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `a = [1, 2, 3, 4];` you are overriding the argument (which is local to the function) you have passed into the function `test`. You are not making any changes to the actual array `a`.
Now the `a` inside does not even point to the array `a` outside.

But there is a change happening when you do `b.push(4)`, which actually mutates the `b` array outside.

```js
function test(a, b) {
  a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  b.push(4);
}

a = [1, 2, 3];
b = [1, 2, 3];
test(a, b);
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

Comment: ok thanks, I'll mark as right answer, must wait 5 minutes according to SO ;)